# Moving Field from One Module to Another Vtiger

Tags: crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

I have a custom field in custom module `(A)` and i want to move this field to custom module `(B)` as we are not going to use module `(A)` anymore.

Is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the field in B.
2. With an sql query, copy the values from field in A to field in B.
3. Delete field in A.